# React JS Babel unable to compile css file

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to create a React JS App. The error occurs when I am trying to access .classname in css file.

[The image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TUyM.png)

Can someone help me It would be a great help.

Comment: Do you have a .css file and the babel loader for CSS?
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: Yes I am trying to refer the css code inside a .css file and I am trying to use babel-plugin-css-modules-transform

Comment: I have added {
    "plugins": ["css-modules-transform"]
} inside the .babelrc of babel-plugin-css-modules-transform. Is that the correct location?